# Building a simple to do list app. I would like to save the lists to a specific directory. Why won't these save to these specified file location?

Tags: python, save

This is a simple to do list application. I would like to save lists, entered by the user, to a directory. How do I save the files to a specified location? The code below creates a file but does not save it to the directory. (Function - newList)

```
#Set up Directory
tdApp = r'C:Program Files\todolistapp'
if not path.exists(tdApp):
    makedirs(tdApp)

listNames = listdir(tdApp)
listNames = list(listNames)

#Set up the window
window = Tk()
window.title("To-Do List")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)
window.geometry("500x450+500+200")

#Frame
appFrame = Frame(window)
appFrame.pack()

savePath = 'C:\\Apps\\todolistapp\\'

#Define functions
def newList ():
    task = listEntry.get()
    if task != "":
        name = task
        filename = "%s.txt" % name
        completeName = "C:\\Apps\\todolistapp\\" + filename
        print(completeName)
        with open(completeName, "w") as f:
            pass
        tdList.insert(END, task)
        listEntry.delete(0, "end")
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please enter a name for your list.")

#Create entry
listEntry = Entry(window,
                  width=30)
listEntry.pack(pady=30)

#Create a frame for buttons
buttonFrame = Frame(window)
buttonFrame.pack(pady=30)

#Create buttons
addListButton = Button(
    buttonFrame,
    text='Add List',
    height=2,
    width=10,
    command= lambda:(newList()) )
addListButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You write nothing in the file . replace "pass " line by the code to write the content of your file

Answer (score 1):

Because the **savePath** variable isn't complete.

It will save the file on the directory where you run the script + "/todolistapp", or it may save in "C:/todolistapp"

Just use **tdApp** variable to save your file.

Also you are just opening (or creating) and immediately closing the file without writing anything to it. And, when working with files, it's always best to do so using the `with` statement like so:

```
with open(completeName, "w") as f:
   # Do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't work when I use tdApp. I also tried changing the savePath name to "C:/todolistapp" and still no luck.

Comment: @KatNunez this is weird. Have you tried using a temporary custom name as your `completeName`? Or maybe try this: `completeName = "C:\\Program Files\\todolistapp\\" + filename` and see if this works.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `tdApp` because you didn't include a backslash after "C:" (or two backslashes if it's not a raw string, or a single forwardslash)

Comment: I've tried all of those resolutions and still no luck. If I add forward slashes to **tdApp** ('C:/Program Files/todolistapp') I receive an error stating access denied.

Comment: @KatNunez if you're running your script from a terminal (like cmd or PowerShell) try running that terminal as administrator and then run the script from within that terminal.

Comment: This happens because some folders in Windows (like Program Files) require Administrator Privileges even if you just want to read the content (that's why when you install a program in that directory you must give admin privileges to the installer).

Comment: Thank you! I moved the directory to another location. However, now, when I try to create a file in the directory I receive the error **TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

Comment: completeName = "C:\\Apps\\todolisapp\\" + filename
print(completeName)
with open(completeName,"w") as f:
    f.write("test")
    f.close()'

Comment: @KatNunez three things: 1. When using `with` statement you don't need `f.close`. 2. `f.write()`, unlike the `print()` function, does not add a **newline** charachter at the end, so If you need to write to a file in different lines, remember to add `f.write("\n")` after the first `f.write()` call. 3. I don't understand what that error is referring to, can you update your original question with the new code and also say which line gives that error?

Comment: OK. Thank you so much for the feedback. I've updated the original code. The error is occurring at line: **with open(CompleteName, "w") as f:**

Comment: @KatNunez thanks for updating the code. The error **TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer** can't come from `with open(...) as f:` because `open()` arguments can only be `str`. I do see other problems in the code (like `tdApp` not being updated and the `else` statement with wrong indentation). Also in the `addListButton` definition, you shouldn't need to put `newList()` in perentheses. But other than this, I can't identify the problem